Creating own nameservers for the sake of creating own hosting business
How do I create a nameserver on my domain and own server, publically available so that users can add in those nameservers and control all the things (DNS records and all) via our panel?
Ideally, I would go for a self-hosted open-source approach for this. I've researched Google DNS or Azure, but they are paid solutions. I've researched BIND9, but the thing is mostly confusing. Can BIND9 create a public nameserver that a user using our hosting can use so that we can link it to our DNS Zone editor afterward?
I'll use example.com as our domain. Basically, A user adds ns1.example.com to their domain nameserver. I, as a hosting provider, am trying to provide direct access to the DNS editor on something like panel.example.com (similar to how cloudflare provides theirs)
We are either using cPanel or ISPmanager for the panel (most probably cPanel). For OS, we are using Ubuntu.
Edit: since I'm using virtualizor, Shall I use PowerDNS from Virtualizor, it seems easier to get my head around it. If so, can I pair the authoritive DNS with cPanel? I want to make sure that all the system do connect before I make a purchase or start with the idea...

If Bind is confusing you should probably not run a hosting service. It's one of many moving parts in a hosting setup, all of them with some complexity. Without a sound understanding of the moving parts debugging and fault finding will be hard...

Shall I use PowerDNS from Virtualizor, it seems easier to get my head around it. If so, can I pair the authoritive DNS with cPanel? I want to make sure that all the system do connect before I make a purchase or start with the idea.
